# What's Old English for "petal"?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, old-english

What was the Old English word for **petal**? (As in "rose petal".)

I've done research. And it seems the word *petal* is a relatively recent addition in the English language.

[image]

Comment: Looks like many other Germanic languages use a cognate of "blade," but we don't have any attestation of the ancestor of this word being used in this way in Old English. It's possible that the word only got this sense later on in the other languages.

Comment: @sumelic The OP cited the results of a Google search  https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=petal%2C+origin  I know this is not regarded as a kosher source, but I am not sure why.  Maybe you can explain this to the OP.

Answer (score 7):

It would appear that [Shakespeare](http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/views/plays/play_view.php?WorkID=henry6p1&Act=4&Scene=1&Scope=scene&LineHighlight=1854#1854) used "leaves" (and, presumably, "leaf"):

> Crossing the sea from England into France, This fellow here, with
>   envious carping tongue, Upbraided me about the **rose** I wear; Saying,
>   the sanguine colour of the **leaves** Did represent my master's blushing
>   cheeks, When stubbornly he did repugn the truth About a certain
>   question in the law Argued betwixt the Duke of York and him; With
>   other vile and ignominious terms: In confutation of which rude
>   reproach And in defence of my lord's worthiness, I crave the benefit
>   of law of arms.

("Sanguine", of course, has a meaning of "blood red", so it's reasonable to assume that Will did not mean the green leaves on the stem.)

Comment: Great find! The OED suggests that this is particularly common as applied to roses, and actually has an entry on "rose leaf" that has a citation that appears to be from Old English: "[eOE *Bald's Leechbk.* (Royal) (1865) ii. ii. 180   Wiþ sarum magan, **rosan leafa,** v oþþe vii oððe nigon, & pipores corna emfela.]"

Comment: Shakespeare isn't Old English.

Answer (score 4):

Old English (as also the Early Modern English of Shakespeare) distinguished the parts of the leaves. Petals then, as now, are modified leaves. The Old English word approximating the meaning of 'petal' is *blÆd*:

> Old English *blÆd* Modern English *a leaf blade*

(From [*Old English to Modern English Translator*](http://www.oldenglishtranslator.co.uk/), 'leaf'.)

Comment: Is there a reason for Æ instead of æ that I'm missing, or just input limitations?

Comment: @ChrisH, I suspect the capitalization is an artifact of the translator. I retained it in case it was significant (ǣ being represented rather than æ), out of perhaps overzealous respect for the source (it being a quote), and to suit my laziness and haste--all three, or is that four? At least the last have now been nullified. For my part (in my limited knowledge), there is no good reason for the capitalization, and Æ represents æ not ǣ.